# make serverless.yml use existing vpc

Tags: serverless-framework

Is it possible to get a serverless.yml template so substitute in a VPC id for a VPC that already exists in an AWS account?

Me and my colleagues each have our own AWS accounts that are provisioned by our company with a single VPC (and we don't have permission to create our own VPCs) so I want my serverless.yml to be able to, for each person, get the VPC id for that person's account and substitute it in to serverless.yml

Is there a way to do this or with serverless or will it be necessary to parametrise it with an environment variable?

Comment: I dont understand your question, do you need to change the default vpc in the serverless.yml?

Comment: @EduardoDiaz no I need to refer to the default VPC and I need a nice way to get a reference to its VPC id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the VPCs were created through Cloudformation templates, you can [export a stack output value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) for each of your VPC Ids. Then within your `serverless.yml` file you can use the built-in intrinsic function [Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) to read the value of the exported vpc id.

If you aren't using Cloudformation or can't export the vpc id, then I would suggest to add it as a parameter to serverless. I don't personally see harm in having a parameter for VPC ID.

Comment: Thanks - the default VPC isn't exported (because AWS creates as part of an account I guess) so I ended up passing in the VPC id as a command line option.

Comment: @tschumann can you please provide an example of how you specify VPC id in a config then, after you pass it as a command line option?

Comment: @KirkHammett I have my VPC, I use the AWS CLI to get the VPC ID, then I create an environment variable in my deployment script which I then access using ${ENV:vpc_id}

Comment: @tschumann Thanks for providing this information! Can you please tell which parameter do you pass VPC ID to? Is it going to serverless.yml or you use some kind of a custom config / script?

Comment: @KrikHammett yes just through to Serverless. The process that calls Serverless creates an environment variable which Serverless then accesses.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `serverless.yml`

Try to add the vpc on the functions or in the provider section:

In specific function:

```
 functions:
  getAllTrucksTSPFleetilla:
      handler: src/functions/get-all-trip-stop-parking.handler
      vpc:
        securityGroupIds:
          - sg-xxxxxxx1
          - sg-xxxxxxx2
        subnetIds:
          - subnet-xxxxxx1
          - subnet-xxxxxx2
          - subnet-xxxxxx3
```

In all project:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-xxxxxxx1
      - sg-xxxxxxx2
    subnet-xxxxxx1
      - subnet-xxxxxx2
      - subnet-xxxxxx3
```

To get the the security groups and the subnest you need to go to the **VPC service** on the aws console and find this information.

Visit the serverless documentation: [sls vpc docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/)